# How to run multiple angular web sites on the sub pages using docker and nginx?

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, docker-compose, containers

I'm trying to run multiple web sites on one domain and its sub pages.
When I google, I found examples for multiple websites on subdomain.

For example, I have websites as website1, website2 and website3.
I have a domain set for this.
https://docker:8080

I want to run websites like:
website1 on https://docker:8080/website1
website2 on https://docker:8080/website2
website3 on https://docker:8080/website3

How my docker compose file and configurations look like ?

Answer (score 0):

To run multiple websites on a domain and its subpages, you can use Docker's reverse proxy feature. This allows you to redirect incoming HTTP/HTTPS traffic to different Docker containers based on the URL path.

Here's an example Docker Compose file that uses reverse proxy to run three different websites on subpages of https://docker:8080:

version: '3.9'

services:
nginx:
image: nginx
ports:
- "8080:80"
volumes:
- ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
restart: always

website1:
image: your_website1_image
restart: always

website2:
image: your_website2_image
restart: always

website3:
image: your_website3_image
restart: always